# How to tell Django staticfiles to not collect user uploaded media directory files?

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I have a very simple question which I was not able to find an answer. Using Django staticfiles app, I call the statics collect routine by typing this command line : `python manage.py collectstatic`.

My problem is that I've several applications serving statics + a **media directory** containing user-uploaded files. Django copies all the files to the static directory, including media files!

I just would like Django **to not copy user-uploaded files to the static directory** when I call `python manage.py collectstatic`. Does anyone have an idea? Tried `--ignore` option but without success...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: add statisfiles settings here, please

Comment: Is moving user uploaded media to MEDIA_ROOT (where they belong) an option?

Comment: In fact, files are uploaded by user to MEDIA_ROOT. Everything is OK and I can use them in my templates. The problem is that collectstatics copies `MEDIA_ROOT/*` to `STATIC_ROOT`. So I'm affraid it will end to overload my server by duplicating every single user-uploaded file...

Comment: Your MEDIA_ROOT should not be in your STATIC_ROOT.

Comment: it seems to be incorrect staticfiles settings

Comment: I agree with @jpic. `MEDIA_ROOT` is *not* collected into static by default. You'd have to tell Django to do that. Have you perhaps added the same directory to `STATICFILES_DIRS`?

Answer (score 6):

That was a problem of django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder, try removing that from STATICFILES_FINDERS.

Answer (score 0):

So what exactly doesn't work if you use [`--ignore`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-option---ignore)?

Though the real solution is not to mix user generated content and static files.

If you keep both types separated you can easily put your static files under version control and don't have to deal with excludes on this front as well. And in fact the separation from media (user generated) and static files is the rationale behind staticfiles:

> In previous versions of Django, it was common to place static assets
>   in MEDIA_ROOT along with user-uploaded files, and serve them both at
>   MEDIA_URL. Part of the purpose of introducing the staticfiles app is
>   to make it easier to keep static files separate from user-uploaded
>   files.

The docs on this topic are really comprehensive: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/